# Dirichlet marginals - why does Mathematica not give the *Kth* marginal?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Observe:

```
MarginalDistribution[DirichletDistribution[{a, b, c, d}], #] & /@ Range@4
```

> {BetaDistribution[a, b + c + d], BetaDistribution[b, a + c + d],
>   BetaDistribution[c, a + b + d],
>   MarginalDistribution[DirichletDistribution[{a, b, c, d}], 4]}

The marginal of *d* is clearly `BetaDistribution[d, a + b + c]`, unless I'm having a brain spasm. Why does *Mathematica* not output this?

Comment: I don't know. Might it have to do with the fact that the DirichletDistribution has k+1 shape parameters but only k dimensions?

Comment: As a follow up to the previous comment: With four arguments, the PDF of a DirichletDistribution is a three dimensional function, so it can have only three marginals.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Well, unless I'm misinterpreting what you're getting at, that's just plain wrong w/r to number of marginals: *any* of the concentrations can be marginalized out, giving* four* possible simple marginal distributions, and of course any *combination* of concentrations can be marginalized. I guess it comes down to how MMA defines the arguments of the `MarginalDistribution` function, which I find unsatisfying in this case: I have to manually create the MD for the Kth paramter.

Comment: I'm decidedly not an expert in this area, but reading MMA's documentation and other sources like Wikipedia it really looks like that the number of independent dimensions is one less than the number of alphas. Do you at least agree that the number of marginals should be equal to the number of dimensions of the PDF?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Have a look at the [marginals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Marginal_distributions) definition - clearly there are *k* (simple) marginals (where one concentration parameter is marginalized out for each), so no, there's not some "number of marginals is equal to dimensions the simplex is embedded in"... kind of rule. I think it boils down to the way MMA defines the parameters and the way it defines the second argument to `MarginalDistribution`... so it is what it is, and to get the "last" simple marginal I need to do it manually. It is what it is....

Comment: I saw that definition but it did not help me as it describes a single marginal and does not tell how many there are. Also, the PDF on the same page clearly has k-1 random variables. Given that the marginal of a PDF is usually defined in terms of integrating away the other variables it is then understandable that there are only k-1 in mma. HOWEVER, given the k dimensional embedding, and the fact that the dependency of the kth variable on all the others holds for any of the others I **fully agree** with you that there should be four marginals in this case. The Dirichlet distribution is weird...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Yeah, I think I'll write this off as one of those MMA quirky "definitions" (like `PascalDistribution`, that's not the normal Pascal def.). Thanks for interaction - made me think more about this!

Answer (score 7):

It is a matter of definition, of course. Mathematica defines `DirichletDistribution[{a1, a2, a3, a4}]` to be a 3D distribution, compatible with 3D Lebesgue measure.

The definition you have in mind is

```
DirichletDistribution2[avec_List] := 
 Block[{x, n = Length[avec] - 1}, 
  TransformedDistribution[Append[Array[x, n], 1 - Total[Array[x, n]]],
    Distributed[Array[x, n], DirichletDistribution[avec]]]]
```

That is

```
In[249]:= DirichletDistribution2[{a, b, c, d}]

Out[249]= TransformedDistribution[{x1, x2, x3, 1 - x1 - x2 - x3}, 
      {x1, x2, 3} ~Distributed~ DirichletDistribution[{a, b, c, d}]]
```

The marginal distribution then works as you would expect, however the transformed distribution does not recognize the 4-th marginal as a beta distribution out of the box:

```
In[242]:= Table[
 MarginalDistribution[DirichletDistribution2[{a, b, c, d}], k], {k, 4}]

Out[242]= {BetaDistribution[a, b + c + d], 
 BetaDistribution[b, a + c + d], BetaDistribution[c, a + b + d], 
 TransformedDistribution[
  1 - x1 - x2 - x3, {x1, x2, x3} ~Distributed~
   DirichletDistribution[{a, b, c, d}]]}
```

This can be determined by a method of moments, for example:

```
In[257]:= 
m4moments = 
  Table[Moment[
    TransformedDistribution[
     1 - x1 - x2 - x3, {x1, x2, x3} \[Distributed] 
      DirichletDistribution[{a, b, c, d}]], r], {r, 4}];

In[258]:= 
betamoments = Table[Moment[BetaDistribution[alpha, beta], r], {r, 4}];

In[259]:= Solve[
 FunctionExpand[m4moments] == FunctionExpand[betamoments], {alpha, 
  beta}]

Out[259]= {{alpha -> d, beta -> a + b + c}}
```

Comment: That's a nice post, +1

Answer (score 1):

As was noted by Sjoerd C. de Vries in the comments, `DirichletDistribution[{a, b, c, d}]` is a three-dimensional distribution:

```
DistributionDomain@DirichletDistribution[{a, b, c, d}]

(* {Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}]} *)
```

and therefore asking for the fourth marginal isn't defined.

Comment: Hi Stefan, could you please comment on the above comments?